# Repeat data in array how to filter

Tags: php, arrays

This is my basic array:

```
Array (
[1] => array
(
    [name] => Name1
    [midname] => MidN1
    [lastname] => LastN1
    [email] => email_1@email1.com

)
[2] => array
(
    [name] => Name2
    [midname] => MidN2
    [lastname] => LastN2
    [email] => email_1@email1.com

)
[3] => array
(
    [name] => Name1
    [midname] => MidN1
    [lastname] => LastN1
    [email] => email_2@email2.com

)

)
```

As you can see I have names and emails to be the same in some cases, the idea is to display only an array as follow

```
[1] => array
(
    [name] => Name1
    [midname] => MidN1
    [lastname] => LastN1
    [email] => email_1@email1.com

)
[3] => array
(
    [name] => Name1
    [midname] => MidN1
    [lastname] => LastN1
    [email] => email_2@email2.com

)
```

as you can see the name is the same but the email is different, so that is the idea to get all of the information from emails that are different, now, the problem is that name, midname, lastname and email is stored in a single column as json array:
So first I:

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM table";
$r=$con->query($q);
$res = mysqli_fetch_array($r);
$arrs = json_decode($res);
print_r($arrs);
```

and that is how I get the array's ... and they get display in html as:
Name1 MidN1 LastN1 email_1@email1.com
Name2 MidN2 LastN2 email_1@email1.com
Name1 MidN1 LastN1 email_2@email2.com

the idea is to get only:
Name1 MidN1 LastN1 email_1@email1.com
Name1 MidN1 LastN1 email_2@email2.com

I try to use array_unique($array); but that return empty and array_unique($array, SORT_REGULAR); that will output the whole thing, the [1]=>array()... is the ID from the row...

Thank you for taking the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited my answer.
You can iterate your Json result like this:

```
$my_array = array();
foreach ($arrs as $key => $value) {
    if (!in_array($value['email'], $my_array)){
        $my_array[] = $value['email'];
    }
}
```

However I wonder why storing a Json string in a DB field instead of using a field per property...

Comment: I think that would work if my table was ID | NAME | EMAIL |... but is not, I only have ID | DATA | ... and in data I have a json with all of the information ... but thanks.

Comment: @Tanker why are you storing all that data into a single column to begin with, is it something a framework you use does?

Comment: Nop, that was someone else before me, and the whole system is using that array, as you can imaging is full of errors, incomplete and hard to manage... I'll migrate the whole thing with a new DB and code, but for now I have to fix it... thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution if you are not able to change your table definition or your query:
1) Making an array where First name, middlename and lastname are primary key
  ( Problem is two John junior Smith)

```
$arr= array (
'1' => array
(
'name' => 'Name1',
'midname' => 'MidN1',
'lastname' => 'LastN1',
'email' => 'email_1@email1.com'

),
'2' => array
(
'name' => 'Name2',
'midname' => 'MidN2',
'lastname' => 'LastN2',
'email' => 'email_1@email1.com'

),
'3' => array
(
'name' => 'Name1',
'midname' => 'MidN1',
'lastname' => 'LastN1',
'email' => 'email_2@email2.com'

)

);
$people = array();
foreach($arr as $v){
$people[$v['name'].' '.$v['name'].' '.$v['name']][] = $v['email'];
}
ksort($people); // if it is not ordered by mysql
echo '<table border="1">';
foreach( $people as $k => $val){
echo "<tr><td>$k</td><td>";
foreach($val as $email){
echo $email.'<br>';
}
echo '</td></tr>';

}
echo '</table>';
```

Another solution is by using usort  where you define your sorting criteria.

Comment: Hello, I think you misunderstood my question, what you just posted is kind of like I have already except for the first foreach... what I was missing was a second array and the IF ...  just like @Slyvain said.. but thank you.